# Skills required to switch a job from Business Analytics to Software Testing

Tags: manual-testing

Currently I'm working as a Business Analyst and I would like to quit my job and become a Test Engineer.

In my current job I do not use any technology so I think getting business analyst job is difficult, opportunities are less. Instead of wasting time searching for a business analyst job, can I become a software tester?  What skills are required?  What might I be missing?

Comment: Can you give more detail?  If you have no technical skills, why do you think you'd have the skills necessary to be a software tester?  What skills do you have?  Why do you want to become a test engineer?

Comment: Manual or automated tester? As BA, you should have all the skills for manual tester. For automated, learn some programming languages. Python is widely considered as best first language, but you will need to learn more languages later.

Comment: Frankly you would need to put your resume up here.  I think it's better to ask a recruiter this or provide a ton more information.  I manage both BA and QA resources and can say it can be done, but it's not just a "I want to do Test instead of BA" and get a happy acceptance.  What skills do you have?  It's impossible to tell you what you are missing without anything listed...

Answer (score 1):

Software testers and business analysts are like two sides of the same coin.
A software tester is a professional responsible for verifying that the software solution satisfies the specified requirements.

You can become a software tester if you possess analytical and logical thinking if you are very attentive to small details. You can attend some courses, or read special books, and start. Software testing is not a science, it is not something that is too difficult. If you’re meticulous if you’re interested in how mechanisms function, then this job is for you. But it requires creativity and flexibility.

Software testers also have been exposed to projects and have experience writing in a clear way through defect reports. Testing and coming up with a test plan requires clear critical thinking too.You need multiple skills which include communication and technical skills as well.

Also, there are some testing certifications for your career improvement, such as ISTQB and CSTE...